# How to make vuex getters reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I working on a schedule with VUE, I'm really new with VUE and with JS. I created VUE component that adds some new properties into the object which already in state and then I take this object with getters and render inside my another VUE component, but unfortunately new properties render only after reloading.
Here is snippet from my component where I add new property

```
    methods: {
                ...mapActions({addDateToState: 'addDate'}),
                addDate () {
                    this.date = this.startTime.time; 
                    //date from datepicker

                    this.addDateToState({date:this.date, year:this.year, time:this.event.time, name:this.event});
                    // object need to add
                },

            }
```

Here is a snippet from state

```
const state = {
    schedule: {}
}
```

Here is actions

```
addDate ({commit}, date) {
        commit('ADD_DATE', date)
    }
```

And here is the mutation which does all the work

```
    ADD_DATE (state, date) {
            if (typeof state.schedule[date.year] === 'undefined') {
                state.schedule[date.year] = {};
            }

            if (typeof state.schedule[date.year][date.date] === 'undefined') {
                state.schedule[date.year][date.date] = {};
            }
            if (typeof state.schedule[date.year][date.date][date.time] === 'undefined') {
                state.schedule[date.year][date.date][date.time] = [];
            }
            state.schedule[date.year][date.date][date.time].push(date.name)
            //interesting that this properties are reactive, so I see chenges when pushh new element to the array, but don't see if it is new property on the object

            console.log(state.schedule)
            //here I see the schedule which already has new properties so mutation works

        }
```

Getters

```
const getters = {
schedule() {
        return state.schedule;
    }
}
```

And here is computed property which get the schedule from getters

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
        'schedule'
    ])
}
```

So the problem that I can't make this getter reactive, but I see that state was changed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Vue.set/this.$set if you are adding new property. See vue [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: I don't understand this method to the end. I tried it before and replace my mutations to the `Vue.set(state.schedule, date.year, {})` for example. And I have error in console ` Vue is not defined` and `this.$set is not a function` with `this.$set(state.schedule, date.year, {})`. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: and as I understand this set the property to the object, but console shows me that I already done this and the problem is when I'm trying to render it

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko it is set, but it isnt reactive. Vue dont know when it changes so it cant update\rerender when it changes. As for this.$set - its not available in vuex. As for Vue.set -> obviously u need to import Vue first.
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules - see more examples here specifically for vuex

Comment: Man! Thanks, I was struggling with this for a while.

Answer (score -1):

me, when i need a reactive getter in vue a do that:

```
computed: {
    getSchedule: function () { return this.schedule; }
}
```

Comment: still not reactive. Getters should be reactive by default, but there is some problem with adding new properties to an objects and I don't know how to solve it